# Replace One CSV Field With Another Through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

In PowerShell I'm importing a CSV `SAMTemp2` which will have a field called `SO`.  Sometimes `SO` will be populated with "NW" and in these cases I just want to pull the field called `ProdProj` from the same line and replace the data in `SO` with the data in `ProdProj` then export it the data in that condition.

```
$RepNW = Import-Csv $SAMTemp2
foreach($d in $data){
If($d.SO -eq "NW"){($d.SO).Replace($d.ProdProj)}}
$RepNW | Export-Csv $SAMTemp -NoTypeInformation
```

I don't get an error, but this doesn't seem to do anything, either.  Can anyone assist me, please?

## Update

Per Matt below, I tried:

```
$RepNW = Import-Csv $SAMTemp2
foreach($d in $RepNW){
If($d.SO -eq "NW"){$d.SO = ($d.SO).Replace($d.ProdProj)}}
$RepNW | Export-Csv $SAMTemp -NoTypeInformation
```

But I'm not seeing any change.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You are not writing the changes back. `$d.SO = ($d.SO).Replace($d.ProdProj)` should do it. Other improvement might help as well.

Comment: where does $data come from? You read into var $RepNW

Comment: @LotPings >.<; thanks.  I missed that.

Comment: @Matt where do I put that?  I tried `If($d.SO -eq "NW"){$d.SO = ($d.SO).Replace($d.ProdProj)}}` but the fields still report as "NW".

Comment: Your replace is flawed maybe. Are you just chenging the value completely ?  Why are you using replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As LotPings pointed out in this line `foreach($d in $data){`, you haven't defined `$data` and it seems that you mean it to be `foreach($d in $RepNW){`

Secondly, rather than using `Replace()` you can just set one property to be equal to the other.

Last, this probably easiest to do all in the pipeline with `ForEach-Object`

```
Import-Csv $SAMTemp2 | ForEach-Object {
    If($_.SO -eq "NW"){
        $_.SO = $_.ProdProj
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv $SAMTemp -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks all!  This was the answer.  And @Matt you're right about my flawed replace.  I have a lot of flaws, and not just in scripting.